# Is there a fluent way of defining error queue in Nservicebus 3

Tags: c#, nservicebus, nservicebus3

I'm wondering if I can define the location of the error queue for my application using the fluent (Configure.With()) syntax?

Note this has changed in nservicebus3 to be configured via MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way since we want to push users to put that setting in the config so that OPS can change it without a recompile. That said you can override where NSB reads the setting and put that in code instead. Do this by implementing:

IProvideConfiguration

Here is an example on how to do it:

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/Samples/PubSub/Subscriber1/ConfigOverride.cs

Comment: I was working for a company until recently, which uses NserviceBus extensible. The architecture was a complete fiasco but the worst part of it was the magic going on under the wood, because there were a lot of convetions. Debugging was not easy with NServiceBus and if you have a lot of things happening without you having a config to look at, it becomes even more complicated.

Comment: In same case if you have been working for a while with some software, convention are grand, but if you just moved in, configuration is also a good thing. I just think that forcing everyone to go the convention over configuration path is not a good idea, the choice should be there for both cases.